# zookeeper vs redis server sync

Tags: redis, distributed, apache-zookeeper

I have a small cluster of servers I need to keep in sync.  My initial thought on this was to have one server be the "master" and publish updates using redis's pub/sub functionality (since we are already using redis for storage) and letting the other servers in the cluster, the slaves, poll for updates in a long running task.  This seemed to be a simple method to keep everything in sync, but then I thought of the obvious issue:  What if my "master" goes down?  That is where I started looking into techniques to make sure there is always a master, which led me to reading about ideas like leader election.  Finally, I stumbled upon [Apache Zookeeper](https://zookeeper.apache.org/) (through python binding, "[pettingzoo](https://github.com/Knewton/pettingzoo-python)"), which apparently takes care of a lot of the fault tolerance logic for you.  I may be able to write my own leader selection code, but I figure it wouldn't be close to as good as something that has been proven and tested, like Zookeeper.

My main issue with using zookeeper is that it is just another component that I may be adding to my setup unnecessarily when I could get by with something simpler.  Has anyone ever used redis in this way?  Or is there any other simple method I can use to get the type of functionality I am trying to achieve?

More info about pettingzoo ([slideshare](http://www.slideshare.net/devondjones/a-python-petting-zoo))

Answer (score 18):

I'm afraid there is no simple method to achieve high-availability. This is usually tricky to setup and tricky to test. There are multiple ways to achieve HA, to be classified in two categories: physical clustering and logical clustering.

**Physical clustering** is about using hardware, network, and OS level mechanisms to achieve HA. On Linux, you can have a look at [Pacemaker](http://clusterlabs.org/) which is a full-fledged open-source solution coming with all enterprise distributions. If you want to directly embed clustering capabilities in your application (in C), you may want to check the [Corosync cluster engine](http://www.corosync.org/) (also used by Pacemaker). If you plan to use commercial software, [Veritas Cluster Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Veritas_Cluster_Server) is a well established (but expensive) cross-platform HA solution.

**Logical clustering** is about using fancy distributed algorithms (like leader election, PAXOS, etc ...) to achieve HA without relying on specific low level mechanisms. This is what things like Zookeeper provide.

Zookeeper is a consistent, ordered, hierarchical store built on top of the ZAB protocol (quite similar to PAXOS). It is quite robust and can be used to implement some HA facilities, but it is not trivial, and you need to install the JVM on all nodes. For good examples, you may have a look at some [recipes](http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/trunk/recipes.html) and the excellent [Curator](https://github.com/netflix/curator) library from Netflix. These days, Zookeeper is used well beyond the pure Hadoop contexts, and IMO, this is the best solution to build a HA logical infrastructure.

Redis pub/sub mechanism is not reliable enough to implement a logical cluster, because unread messages will be lost (there is no queuing of items with pub/sub). To achieve HA of a collection of Redis instances, you can try Redis [Sentinel](http://redis.io/topics/sentinel), but it does not extend to your own software.

If you are ready to program in C, a HA framework which is often forgotten (but can be quite useful IMO) is the one coming with [BerkeleyDB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/products/berkeleydb/high-availability-099050.html). It is quite basic but support off-the-shelf leader elections, and can be integrated in any environment. Documentation can be found [here](http://www.oracle.com/us/technologies/ha-scalable-applications-bdb-wp-166559.pdf) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17076_02/html/programmer_reference/rep.html). Note: you do not have to store your data with BerkeleyDB to benefit from the HA mechanism (only the topology data - the same ones you would put in Zookeeper).